# Unable to set index as x axis

Tags: python

I have the following DF :

```
    A Index B Index C Index D Index
    PX_LAST PX_LAST PX_LAST PX_LAST
2021-12-31  1.5101  0.195   -2.101  -0.509
2022-01-03  1.628   0.244   -2.032  -0.468
2022-01-04  1.6473  0.233   -2.074  -0.511
2022-01-05  1.7052  0.229   -2.045  -0.468
2022-01-06  1.7211  0.261   -1.965  -0.37
2022-01-07  1.762   0.285   -1.97   -0.338
2022-01-10  1.7603  0.284   -1.964  -0.361
2022-01-11  1.7357  0.347   -1.961  -0.348
2022-01-12  1.7428  0.321   -1.995  -0.384
2022-01-13  1.7041  0.288   -1.993  -0.394
2022-01-14  1.7841  0.332   -1.959  -0.352
2022-01-17  1.7841  0.355   -1.948  -0.339
2022-01-18  1.8735  0.368   -1.941  -0.311
2022-01-19  1.8646  0.38    -1.924  -0.283
2022-01-20  1.804   0.363   -1.918  -0.306
2022-01-21  1.7581  0.332   -1.925  -0.291
2022-01-24  1.7706  0.305   -1.959  -0.28
2022-01-25  1.7689  0.331   -1.954  -0.294
2022-01-26  1.8637  0.336   -1.951  -0.265
2022-01-27  1.7994  0.344   -1.943  -0.33
2022-01-28  1.7694  0.367   -1.95   -0.365
2022-01-31  1.7767  0.424   -1.969  -0.402
```

When I try to plot it doing :

```
df.plot(x=df.index,y=["A Index","B Index","X Index","D Index"])
```

it does throw the following issue

```
KeyError: "Index([2021-12-31, 2022-01-03, 2022-01-04, 2022-01-05, 2022-01-06, 2022-01-07,\n       2022-01-10, 2022-01-11, 2022-01-12, 2022-01-13,\n       ...\n       dtype='object', length=135) not in index"
```

[image]

What are these '\n'? How can I plot this DF ?

Many Thanks

Comment: Plotting by index is the default behavior if no `x` is specified. The `\n` are likely just a representation of the newline characters in the error message.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi How easy was this... thank you v much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\n` are likely just a representation of the newline characters in the error message.

Plotting by index is the default behavior if no `x` is specified. `df.plot(y=["A Index", "B Index"])` gives

[image]